# mongo aggregate match expr not working, but expr seems fine

Tags: python, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a Mongo collection, and i'am searching in unwound list of subdocuments from an array using a self made substr match in an $expr, looking like
`{"$expr": {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$ok_name"}, "be"]}, -1]}}`

Funny thing is the `$expr` for `name` in `$match` never matches, as gives zero results, but the same $expr in a `$projection` gives the expected results (`true` and `false` values).

And even funnier the same `$expr` for other fields, e.g. `ok_name`, from the same subdocument works fine.

And other $expr also work fine, see `a_date`.

The whole command looks a bit like this, some parts are missing here for clarity:

```js
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"mergedAt": {"$exists": true}}}, 
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$bar", "includeArrayIndex": "arrayIndex"}}, 
  { "$match": {
    "$and": [
        {"$expr": {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$ok_name"}, "be"]}, -1]}},
        {"$expr": {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$name"}, "e"]}, -1]}}, 
        {"a_date": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-03-01 00:00:00+00:00")}},
    ]
  }
}, 
{"$addFields": {"lastModified_doc": "$lastModified"}}, 
{"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", "$bar"]}}}, 
// {"$unset": [ ... ]
}, 
 { $project: {
"name": 1 , 
"my_expr":  {"$gt": [ {"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$name"}, "e"]}, -1] }} },
// { "$facet": { [...] }}
])
```

So, why does the expr work in for some fields but not others, but always in the `$projection`stage?

I checked types (everything  i use `$indexOfCP` on is a string), order of statements (doesn't matter), and mongo indexes (doesn't matter), and $expr with different types (e.g. dates as in "a_date"), using python motor/pymongo/SON and a mongo shell (Robo3T), ...

What can cause the expr with indexOfCP in match to fail every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood how $expr works, $expr allows you to use aggregation expressions inside a normal query. Putting it here inside $match really has no point. Just try unnesting condition from $expr document and it should work.

Comment: i get an error  "unknown top level operator: $gt" ... :/

```javascript
{ "$match": {
    "$and": [
         {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$kk_name"}, "be"]}, -1]},
        {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$name"}, "e"]}, -1]}, 
        {"rechnung_datum": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-01-02")}},
    ]
  }
```

But perhaps i'm really thinking to complicated...

Comment: i found something working after a few tries and "unknown top level operator: $gt" errors.
The whole match can be an expr:

```javascript
{ "$match": 
      { "$expr": {
        "$and": [
            {"$gte": [ "$rechnung_datum", ISODate("2020-01-02")]},
            {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$kk_name"}, "be"]}, -1]},
            {"$gt": [{"$indexOfCP": [{"$toLower": "$einzelnachweis.name"}, "e"]}, -1]}, 
        ]
    }},
} 
```
needs some reorder of queries but seems to work.
Will check later...

Thx for the hint...

Comment: this approach looks a bit strange but that's mongo... :/